# How to make the array output step by step

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I do so, but something displays already slightly rearranged array. I do not understand why. Or so it should be? Is it still possible to implement this idea?

The essence of quicksort is to shuffle the elements of the array so that it is divided into 2 parts. The first contains elements that are less than or equal to 'p', and the second contains elements greater than or equal to 'p'. Then we sort each part separately.

Generally speaking, it is highly desirable to choose 'p' such that the array is split in half. Please note that 'p' can be any element (not necessarily from the middle of the array) and not even necessarily from this array.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    
void funcprint( int arr[], int size )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
    
int *ar; 
    
void quickSort( int a[], long N ) {
    if( N < 2 )
        return;
    
    long i = 0, j = N - 1;
    int p = a[N >> 1];
    
    while( i < j ) {
        while( a[i] < p ) i++;
        while( a[j] > p ) j--;
    
        if( i < j )
            swap( a[i++], a[j--] );
    }
    funcprint( ar, 9 ); 
    quickSort( a, j );
    quickSort( a + i, N - i );
}
    
int main() {
    int a[10] = { 1,2,3,4,1,2,6,7,8 };
    //int a[10] = { 5,2,1,9,1,4,6,2,0 };
    ar = a; 
    int N = 8;
    quickSort( a, N );
    funcprint( a, N+1 );
}
```

Comment: What does this code result in printing? How doesn't that match what you think it should print? Why do you think that might be?

Comment: You can ask code review related question here -> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it is necessary that step by step deduces permutations

Comment: It's displaying partially sorted results because there's a call to `funcPrint` near the end of `quickSort`, before it recurses.

Comment: where else do you need to call it?

Comment: @Perette ???????

Comment: If you only want to see the final, sorted data, remove `funcPrint` from `quickSort`.  If you're trying to watch `quickSort` progress through sorting, move the `funcPrint` so it runs just after `swap`.

Answer (score 1):

To visualize your code's work you can highlight the subarrays that are being sorted in each iteration.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void funcprint(int arr[], int size, int fragment_start, int fragment_end) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == fragment_start)
            cout << "[ ";
        if (i == fragment_end)
            cout << "] ";
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    if (fragment_end == size)
            cout << "] ";
    cout << endl;
}

int *ar;

void quickSort(int a[], long N) {

    if( N < 2 )
        return;

    long i = 0, j = N - 1;
    int p = a[N >> 1];

    while(i < j) {
        while(a[i] < p)
            i++;
        while(a[j] > p)
            j--;
        if(i < j)
            swap(a[i++], a[j--]);
    }

    funcprint(ar, 9, (a-ar), (a-ar) + N + 1);
    quickSort(a, j);
    quickSort(a + i, N - i);
}

int main() {
    int a[10] = { 1,2,3,4,1,2,6,7,8 };
    ar = a;
    int N = 8;
    cout << "Initial" << endl;
    funcprint(ar, N+1, 0, N+1);
    cout << endl;
    quickSort(a, N);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "After sorting" << endl;
    funcprint(a, N+1, 0, N+1);
}
```

This code's output:

```
Initial
[ 1 2 3 4 1 2 6 7 8 ] 

[ 1 2 3 4 1 2 6 7 8 ] 
1 [ 1 3 4 2 2 6 7 8 ] 
1 1 [ 2 2 4 3 6 7 8 ] 
1 1 2 2 [ 4 3 6 7 8 ] 
1 1 2 2 [ 3 4 6 ] 7 8 
1 1 2 2 3 4 [ 6 7 8 ] 

After sorting
[ 1 1 2 2 3 4 6 7 8 ]
```

And for the `int a[10] = { 5,2,1,9,1,4,6,2,0 };`:

```
Initial
[ 5 2 1 9 1 4 6 2 0 ] 

[ 1 1 2 9 5 4 6 2 0 ] 
1 1 [ 2 2 4 5 6 9 0 ] 
1 1 [ 2 2 4 ] 5 6 9 0 
1 1 2 2 4 [ 5 6 9 0 ] 
1 1 2 2 4 5 [ 6 9 0 ] 

After sorting
[ 1 1 2 2 4 5 6 9 0 ]
```

If you want to see each swap, you can use this approach:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void funcprint(int arr[], int size, int fragment_start, int fragment_end) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == fragment_start)
            cout << "[ ";
        if (i == fragment_end)
            cout << "] ";
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    if (fragment_end == size)
            cout << "] ";
    cout << endl;
}

void printswap(int arr[], int size, int first, int second) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == first || i == second)
            cout << "<" << arr[i] << "> ";
        else
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int *ar;

void quickSort(int a[], long N) {

    if( N < 2 )
        return;

    long i = 0, j = N - 1;
    int p = a[N >> 1];
    int iteration = 1;

    while(i < j) {
        while(a[i] < p)
            i++;
        while(a[j] > p)
            j--;
        if(i < j) {
            swap(a[i++], a[j--]);
            cout << "swap at " << iteration << " iteration:" << endl;
            printswap(ar, 9, (a-ar) + i-1, (a-ar) + j+1);
        }
        ++iteration;
    }

    funcprint(ar, 9, (a-ar), (a-ar) + N + 1);
    quickSort(a, j);
    quickSort(a + i, N - i);
}

int main() {
    int a[10] = { 1,2,3,4,1,2,6,7,8 };
    ar = a;
    int N = 8;
    cout << "Initial" << endl;
    funcprint(ar, N+1, 0, N+1);
    cout << endl;
    quickSort(a, N);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "After sorting" << endl;
    funcprint(a, N+1, 0, N+1);
}
```

Output:

```
[ 1 2 3 4 1 2 6 7 8 ] 

swap at 1 iteration:
<1> 2 3 4 <1> 2 6 7 8 
[ 1 2 3 4 1 2 6 7 8 ] 
swap at 1 iteration:
1 <1> 3 4 <2> 2 6 7 8 
1 [ 1 3 4 2 2 6 7 8 ] 
swap at 1 iteration:
1 1 <2> 4 2 <3> 6 7 8 
swap at 2 iteration:
1 1 2 <2> <4> 3 6 7 8 
1 1 [ 2 2 4 3 6 7 8 ] 
1 1 2 2 [ 4 3 6 7 8 ] 
swap at 1 iteration:
1 1 2 2 <3> <4> 6 7 8 
1 1 2 2 [ 3 4 6 ] 7 8 
1 1 2 2 3 4 [ 6 7 8 ] 

After sorting
[ 1 1 2 2 3 4 6 7 8 ]
```

And for the `int a[10] = { 5,2,1,9,1,4,6,2,0 };`:

```
Initial
[ 5 2 1 9 1 4 6 2 0 ] 

swap at 1 iteration:
<1> 2 1 9 <5> 4 6 2 0 
swap at 2 iteration:
1 <1> <2> 9 5 4 6 2 0 
[ 1 1 2 9 5 4 6 2 0 ] 
swap at 1 iteration:
1 1 2 <2> 5 4 6 <9> 0 
swap at 2 iteration:
1 1 2 2 <4> <5> 6 9 0 
1 1 [ 2 2 4 5 6 9 0 ] 
swap at 1 iteration:
1 1 <2> <2> 4 5 6 9 0 
1 1 [ 2 2 4 ] 5 6 9 0 
1 1 2 2 4 [ 5 6 9 0 ] 
1 1 2 2 4 5 [ 6 9 0 ] 

After sorting
[ 1 1 2 2 4 5 6 9 0 ]
```

This code is kinda messy. Just to show the point.